# Using class and specific font in XeLaTeX throws error

Tags: fonts, xetex, document-classes

I am trying to use [xelatex](/questions/tagged/xelatex) with its own class and a font I found on [another stackexchange site](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/20690).

Here's a minimum working example, the `Roboto` font is in the same folder in a subdirectory called `Roboto`. The content of `a.tex` is:

```
\documentclass[]{b}
\begin{document}
some text
\end{document}
```

and the content of `b.cls` is:

```
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{Roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf}
```

Then I am running

```
xelatex a.tex
```

and get the following error:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/Roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf(0)/m' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 2.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   n
l.2 ..., Color=textcolor]{Roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf}
```

Anyone can help me solving this?

I am on Debian Wheezy and using texlive 2013

Comment: You can't have a class file that short you need at least define the normal font size. add `\LoadClass{article}` as the first line (untested as I don't have the font)

Comment: Thanks. I do have `\LoadClass{article}` in my class, I just removed it to make the MWE. I added it to the MWE in the question, the error stays the same.

Comment: Where is the font relative to the directory containing `a.tex`? To put this another way, why `Roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf` rather than `Roboto-Light.ttf` or the full path? Is the font installed correctly? Can you use it in other applications?

Comment: I can't use it in other applications, I intended to use it only in this LaTeX document. The `Roboto` folder is in the same directory as the `tex` files.

Comment: If you are putting the font in a non-standard location, you should probably include the path (e.g., `Path = /path/to/where/font/is/`) as part of the `\setmainfont` command.  I'd probably also include a `Extension = .ttf`, but it shouldn't be necessary.  In the end, however, why not simply install the font where font's belong..? cfr's point about adding a directory call to the *name* of the font is not a good idea (and probably would only work, if ever, by accident).

Comment: Thanks, that worked in the end. I had the font installed, but it coulnd't find the fonts when using texlive 2012, after putting them in the same folder it worked, but I ran into another problem. So I installed texlive 2013 with the fonts still local, I didn't realize that the error message is connected to missing fonts. I still don't understand it, but it works.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was a localized issue solved by some unknown set of uninstall/reinstall steps.